# Can't inject location using Tizen Emulator (wearable)

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-emulator

I got the Tizen platform emulator to run (showing the hands, loading my app, etc.), but when I try to use the control panel to inject the location, I get an error saying "This page can't load Google Maps directly" (looks like an error coming from Google Maps directly", first image below). After that, I can click on the map, or use manual entry to add location, but when I click Inject Marker/ Inject Location, the UI changes to allow me to cancel, but never progresses past this point (Second image below). I can still press cancel, but retrying doesn't change the outcome). Does anyone know how to get around this issue?

[image: Tizen control panel failing to load Google Maps]
[image: Tizen control panel doesn't inject coordinates successfully]

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue on my emulator. Even though the error message from Google Maps is shown, I was able to successfully inject the latitude and longitude and check its values in web application. I just ignored the error message from Google Maps, clicked 'Ok' and then set the marker the same way you did.

The second screenshot you shared seem to be valid from my experience. You injected the marker to the device and the location was changed (you can cancel it anytime, but until then you can check location and it will match the values you injected).

I did it using web application and JavaScript code as:

*navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((s) => {console.log("Position: (" + s.coords.latitude + ", " + s.coords.longitude + ")")})*

Which returned to me:

*Position: (37.259598, 127.052801)*

After you cancel the location in Control Panel, the location will be cleared and above code will not return any result.